# Largest sum of 13 adjacent numbers

Tags: java

I'm working on the 8th of the Project Euler problems. The script is supposed to find the largest product of 13 adjacent numbers. My answer is `2091059712` but project Euler says this is wrong.
My expected output is `23514624000` (what Project Euler says is the correct answer), however this isn't what I get. Can anyone help me? All help is appreciated, thanks!

Here's the code:

```
public class Script_8
{
    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        String number = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        int length = number.length();
        System.out.println(length);
        int[] numbers_array;
        long total;
        numbers_array = new int[length];
        for ( int i = 0; i < length; i ++)
        {
            numbers_array[i] = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i, i + 1));
        }
        long highest_total = 0L;
        for ( int x = 0; x < length-12; x ++)
        {
            total = (numbers_array[x] * numbers_array[x+1] * numbers_array[x+2] * numbers_array[x+3] * numbers_array[x+4] * numbers_array[x+5] * numbers_array[x+6] * numbers_array[x+7] * numbers_array[x+8] * numbers_array[x+9] * numbers_array[x+10] * numbers_array[x+11] * numbers_array[x+12]);
            System.out.println(total);
            System.out.println(highest_total);
            if ( total > highest_total )
            {
                highest_total = total;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(highest_total);
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3788176). But consider why they might have chosen such an unusual number as *13* consecutive digits.

Comment: Why is the program outputting the wrong answer? Thanks!

Comment: How are either of your results not `0`? `n * 0` is `0`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch because not every 13 digit subsequence contains a zero.

Comment: change `int[] numbers_array;` to `long[] numbers_array;`

Comment: @AndyTurner Agreed. But `2091059712` does.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but 2091059712 isn't in the input sequence. That's the product of 13 consecutive digits.

Comment: Wow SO is cranky tonight. Your question is obvious, I thought

Answer (score 2):

Change `int[] numbers_array` to `long[] numbers_array` to avoid overflow during multiplication of 12 integers. You will also need to use `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I usually write in python so I'm not used to having to deal with overflow, lol.